# Visual Studio Code ignores debug symbols

Tags: c, linux, gcc, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug C using visual studio code on a Mint VM, code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int numargs, char* argvector[])
{
   printf("test\n");
  return(0);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
gcc test.c -g -o test
```

based on the output of ls -l, I can verify that gcc is adding symbols.
When I attempt to debug this program using vs-code using the C/C++ extension, I receive the following error:

```
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Breakpoint 1, main (numargs=1, argvector=0x7fffffffdd18) at test.c:5
5     printf("test\n");
[Inferior 1 (process 8322) exited normally]
The program '/home/ccsd/test/test' has exited with code 0 (0x00000000).
```

gcc version: 5.4.0 20160609

vs-c version: 1.24.1

my launch.json file is as follows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/grow",
            "processName": "grow",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
             ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You may note that this is not a duplicate of [Stopped due to shared library event - Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071176/stopped-due-to-shared-library-event-visual-studio-code) because I am already using the -g switch.

I would like to know how I can fix this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/115

Comment: not really, based on my reading, my launch.json files should already be compliant to the solution the guy found, I seem to be having the same error with launch as he did, which was not fixed, and I'm having the same error using attach.

Comment: Add the compiler and VSC versions to your post.

Comment: done, added my launch.json as well.

Comment: I would suggest that the github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues page is probably your best place to start. If you do eventually get an answer over there, please circle back and answer your own question here.

Comment: I'll think about porting this post over, but I think I've wasted enough time trying to get this working as it is, I'm just going to have to learn a new debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the use of `"additionalSOLibSearchPath"` option of `launch.json` did not help, the following setting **might** add a shared library into `gdb`'s consideration:

```
"setupCommands":[
    {
        "description": "Additional libs for gdb",
        "text": "set solib-search-path sharedLibraryPath/lib"
    }
]
```

PS: `gdb` may still raise `Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)` warning, nevertheless.